# Delphi - inherit from a class and an interface (adapter pattern)?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface, delphi-2007

I am trying to do the GoF adapter pattern and in the C# example that I am following the Adapter class is inheriting the original class and an adapting interface.
In Delphi (2007), as far as I know, this is not possible, or is it? Cause if a class is inheriting an interface, it needs to inherit from TInterfacedObject and since Delphi doesn't allow multiple class inheritance, that is the end of story. I cannot inherit from a custom class and an interface at the same time.

Am I correct?

Thank you.

I have implemented this pattern on http://delphipatterns.blog.com/2011/02/22/decorator-5/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No that it not correct.  You can add an interface to any class you like as follows:

```
type
  IAdapter = interface
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  TAdapter = class(TBaseClass, IInterface, IAdapter)
  private
    FRefCount: Integer;
    procedure DoSomething;
  protected
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  end;

function TAdapter.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TAdapter._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedIncrement(FRefCount);
end;

function TAdapter._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
end;

procedure TAdapter.DoSomething;
begin
end;
```

Comment: +1 I was just to give an example from my text editor suit: `TCustomTextEditor = class(TCustomControl, ISyntaxEditor, ITextEditor)`.

Comment: @Andreas TCustomControl already implement IInterface doesn't it, otherwise you would have had to call it out in that declaration.

Comment: @David: Yes, I was hesitating (otherwise I would've beaten you!). Still, at least it doesn't inherit from `TInterfacedObject`. (Yes, here it is: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TComponent.)

Comment: @Andreas You don't like TInterfacedObject? I see you've crossed the 200 barrier on the Delphi tag!

Comment: @David: What "200 barrier" are you talking about?

Comment: @David: Oh, God. I've never been that high before. I guess you are like a "pace-setter" to me and the rest of the Delphi SO community...

Comment: @David: Thank you. Does this mean that I can inherit from any interface and custom base class as long as I inherit from IInterface as well and implement QueryInterface, _AddRef and _Release?

Comment: @elector Yes that is correct. The rules are that any class that implements an interface has to implement IInterface too. The code I presented here is lifted directly from TInterfacedObject.

Comment: @David Cheers, David. I think you just missed a protected FRefCount field in the code there? I have implemented my Adapter using this.

Comment: @elector I'd make FRefCount private if I were you, maybe even strict private