# Extend delphi class hierarchy

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, interface

I am wondering how to extend a class hierarchy with additional capabilities, following this requisites: 
1) I cannot touch the original hierarchy
2) I need to develop the new features into a different unit

Take for example the following class hierarchy in **uClasses.pas** unit:

```
TBaseClass = class
  ID : Integer;
  Name : String;
end;

TDerivedClass = class(TBaseClass)
  Age : Integer
  Address : String
end;
```

I want to attach other functionality to the classes, for example saving itself to text (it is just an example). So I imagined the following unit **uClasses_Text.pas**:

```
uses uClasses;

Itextable = interface
  function SaveToText: String;
end;

TBaseClass_Text = class(TBaseClass, Itextable)
  function SaveToText: String;
end;

TDerivedClass_Text = class(TDerivedClass, ITextable)
  function SaveToText: String;
end;

function TBaseClass_Text.SaveToText: String;
begin
  result := Self.ID + ' ' + Self.Name;
end;

function TDerivedClass_Text.SaveToText: String;
begin
  // SaveToText on derived class must call SaveToText from the "BaseClass" and then append its additional fields  
  result := ???? // Call to TBaseClass_Text.SaveToText. Or better, ITextable(Self.ParentClass).SaveToText;
  result := result + Self.Age + ' ' + Self.Address;
end;
```

How can I refer to "base" implementation of SaveToText from within TDerivedClass_Text.SaveToText? Maybe handling the interface in some way?

Or, 
does exists a better and cleaner approach to this case?

Thanks,

Comment: did you really mean just `result := inherited SaveToText;` ?

Comment: TDerivedClass_Text inherits from TDerivedClass, that has no SaveToText

Comment: There's no multiple inheritance in Delphi so you have to extend each separate branch of the hierarchy.

Comment: Helpers ? https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=delphi+class+helpers

Comment: "How can I refer to "base" implementation of SaveToText
from within TDerivedClass_Text.SaveToText?" You cannot because it does not exist. You actually state this yourself in a comment. You've answered your own question.

Comment: Thank you David. I know I cannot, I was asking if exists any other way way to achieve this

Comment: I like Arioch's Helpers solution, it could work. But I cannot adopt it , because I will need to extend the classes in other directions. Example uClasses_Xml.pas, uClasses_DB.pas, etc. And Delphi supports only 1 class helper for class

Comment: but you can inherit one class helper from previous class helper. Though it would not always be enough of course

Comment: you can also look at JediVCL. They introduced interface for extra features and a class implementing it. Then they created parallel lineup to VCL, each class inherited from VCL class, added interface and had a member var with that class implementing the interface. So while they did not extended base classes, they created their clones, and they could inherit their helper delegate classes. You can google more for it by "delphi interface delegation mixin" (or "delphi interface implementation delegation")

Comment: Perhaps you should step back and consider to use the Visitor pattern.

Comment: About visitor pattern, see [Uwe Raabe's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/26833/uwe-raabe) article [the-visitor-pattern](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2010/08/16/the-visitor-pattern-part-1/).

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by David, you cannot refer to a method in your base class that does not exists.

With class helpers it's possible to solve your question in another way.
The first class helper `TBaseClassHelper` adds a `SaveToText` function and so do the second class helper `TDerivedClassHelper`.
Look at the implementation of this second `SaveToText` function. It calls `inherited SaveToText`.

**Update 2**

The OP wanted separate units for different `SaveTo` implementations. With the help from comments by David and Arioch, it turns out that class helpers can inherit from other class helpers. Here is a complete example:

```
unit uClasses;

type    

  TBaseClass = class
    ID: Integer;
    Name: String;
  end;

  TDerivedClass = class(TBaseClass)
    Age: Integer;
    Address: String;
  end;
```

---

```
unit uClasses_Text;

uses uClasses,uClasses_SaveToText,uClasses_SaveToIni,uClasses_SaveToDB;

type    
  ITextable = interface
    function SaveToText: string;
    function SaveToIni: string;
    function SaveToDB: string;
  end;

  // Adding reference counting through an interface, since multiple inheritance
  // is not possible (TInterfacedObject and TBaseClass) 
  TBaseClass_Text = class(TBaseClass, IInterface, ITextable)
  strict private
    FRefCount: Integer;
  protected
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  end;

  TDerivedClass_Text = class(TDerivedClass, IInterface, ITextable)
  strict private
    FRefCount: Integer;
  protected
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  end;    

implementation

uses Windows;

function TBaseClass_Text.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TBaseClass_Text._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedIncrement(FRefCount);
end;

function TBaseClass_Text._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
end;    

function TDerivedClass_Text.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TDerivedClass_Text._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedIncrement(FRefCount);
end;    

function TDerivedClass_Text._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
end;
```

---

```
unit uClasses_SaveToText;

interface

uses uClasses;

type    
  TBaseClassHelper = class helper for TBaseClass
    function SaveToText: string;
  end;

  TDerivedClassHelper = class helper for TDerivedClass
    function SaveToText: string;
  end;

implementation

function TBaseClassHelper.SaveToText: string;
begin
  Result := 'BaseClass Text info';
end;

function TDerivedClassHelper.SaveToText: string;
begin
  Result := inherited SaveToText;
  Result := Result + ' DerivedClass Text info';
end;
```

---

```
unit uClasses_SaveToIni;

interface

Uses uClasses,uClasses_SaveToText;

type    
  TBaseClassHelperIni = class helper(TBaseClassHelper) for TBaseClass
    function SaveToIni: string;
  end;

  TDerivedClassHelperIni = class helper(TDerivedClassHelper) for TDerivedClass
    function SaveToIni: string;
  end;

implementation

function TBaseClassHelperIni.SaveToIni: string;
begin
  Result := 'BaseClass Ini info';
end;

function TDerivedClassHelperIni.SaveToIni: string;
begin
  Result := inherited SaveToIni;
  Result := Result + ' DerivedClass Ini info';
end;
```

---

```
unit uClasses_SaveToDB;

interface

Uses uClasses,uClasses_SaveToText,uClasses_SaveToIni;

Type    
  TBaseClassHelperDB = class helper(TBaseClassHelperIni) for TBaseClass
    function SaveToDB: string;
  end;

  TDerivedClassHelperDB = class helper(TDerivedClassHelperIni) for TDerivedClass
    function SaveToDB: string;
  end;

implementation

function TBaseClassHelperDB.SaveToDB: string;
begin
  Result := 'BaseClass DB info';
end;

function TDerivedClassHelperDB.SaveToDB: string;
begin
  Result := inherited SaveToDB;
  Result := Result + 'DerivedClass DB info';
end;
```

---

```
program TestClasses;

uses
  uClasses in 'uClasses.pas',
  uClasses_Text in 'uClasses_Text.pas',
  uClasses_SaveToText in 'uClasses_SaveToText.pas',
  uClasses_SaveToIni in 'uClasses_SaveToIni.pas',
  uClasses_SaveToDB in 'uClasses_SaveToDB.pas';
var
  Textable: ITextable;
begin
  Textable := TDerivedClass_Text.Create;
  WriteLn(Textable.SaveToText);
  WriteLn(Textable.SaveToIni);
  WriteLn(Textable.SaveToDB);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

**Update 1**

Reading your comments about the need to implement several aspects of the `SaveToText` I propose a simple piggy-back solution:

```
type
  ITextable = interface
    function SaveToText: String;
  end;
  TMyTextGenerator = class(TInterfacedObject,ITextable)
  private
    Fbc : TBaseClass;
  public
    constructor Create( bc : TBaseClass);
    function SaveToText: String;
  end;

{ TMyTextGenerator }

constructor TMyTextGenerator.Create(bc: TBaseClass);
begin
  Inherited Create;
  Fbc := bc;
end;

function TMyTextGenerator.SaveToText: String;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Fbc.ID) + ' ' + Fbc.Name;
  if Fbc is TDerivedClass then
  begin
    Result := Result + ' ' + IntToStr(TDerivedClass(Fbc).Age) + ' ' +
      TDerivedClass(Fbc).Address;
  end;
end;
```

Implement TSaveToIni,TSaveToDB etc, with the same pattern in separate units.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover the `ITextable` angle too. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: As I wrote in another comment, I technically like this solution, it solves the problem in a clean way. But, I cannot use it because of the Delphi limit of 1 class helper for class. I will need to extend my classes in other ways (SaveToXml, SaveToDB, etc), each must reside in a different unit. Thanks

Comment: helpers can inherit of one another as well

Comment: @Arioch'The Can that help work around the 1 helper active at any one point in the code issue?

Comment: that exactly depends upon how this restriction hutrs topic starter.  most obvious way is like when he have TButton, TRadioButton, TExtendedRadioButton - and each class can only have one helper. Then of course TERB should have its own enhancements *plus* those of TRB *plus* those of TB. Righting them time and again in each heleper would be bad surely. But inheriting helpers, maybe would make it possible. I did not digged into helpers inheritance but i hope it canbe used to overcome this.

Comment: @Arioch'The class helper inheritance can indeed help work around the 1 active helper issue. Sadly helper inheritance doesn't work for record helpers for some reason: [QC#107781](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107781)

Comment: probably they just fast-hacked register type parser to include helper keyword and forgotten that helper is object and can allow "(parent)" clause. But  now as XE3 is coming they mayeb would look into this. (sorry my bitterness, i have my own QCs and feel disgruntled a bit now)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I had to add a base object that inherits from `TInterfacedObject` to get the interface part working from your edit. Also added a complete solution based on inheritance of class helpers.

Comment: @Arioch'The, thanks for the tip about class helper inheritance. Never heard about it before. It was indeed possible to implement a working solution here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, got it thanks to your answer here: [Delphi - inherit from a class and an interface (adapter pattern)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5353656/576719). Added the reference counting through an interface and removed the dependance of `TInterfacedObject` in the `TBaseClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Delphi does not support multiple inheritance of classes, you are pushed towards solutions like this:

```
function BaseClassSaveToText(obj: TBaseClass): string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(obj.ID) + ' ' + obj.Name;
end;

function TBaseClass_Text.SaveToText: String;
begin
  Result := BaseClassSaveToText(Self);
end;

function DerivedClassSaveToText(obj: TDerivedClass): string;
begin
  Result := BaseClassSaveToText(obj) + IntToStr(obj.Age) + ' ' + obj.Address;
end;

function TDerivedClass_Text.SaveToText: String;
begin
  Result := DerivedClassSaveToText(Self);
end;
```

In `DerivedClassSaveToText` you would like to use the `inherited` keyword, but you cannot because these two classes do not share the necessary common ancestor.

**Update:** @LU RD shows how to do it all with class helpers. Personally I'm a little allergic to class helpers. And of course, there may be other reasons why you don't wish to use helpers. For example, if you are using a legacy version of Delphi then they don't exist.

Comment: Thank you David, this could work, but it needs each class to be aware of which hierarcy level belongs. I wanted to avoid this, as I will handle very complex hierarchy.

Comment: I know, that's the downside. Beyond class helpers I can't see any way around that.

Comment: @David, having to move old codebase when libraries were radically redesigned like DevEx, then helpers are of great help. They surely are workarounds rather than solutions. But for certain classes of situations they are of great help.

Comment: frankly, interface delegation and mirror class tree is not beautiful solution either :-)

Answer (score 1):

Honesty is overrated according to ... (Can't remember the song). I think many of us are overrating inheritance and are often too quick in solving issues with inheritance rather than composition or delegation.

I really question the desire to add a SaveToFile method to each and every class that you want to be able to persist to file.

In my view, classes should be ignorant of responsibilities that are not the reason for their existence. Persistence is one such responsibility, printing another. A printing class should be responsible for printing. Of course you woulnd't want a printing class to be a hornets nets of if statements to deal with every perceivable class you want to print. So you define a Printer base class and extend it with PeoplePrinter, LocationPrinter and WhateverPrinter descendants. Each of which can deal with an entire class hierarchy.

If you are now thinking Decorator pattern, good, well spotted.

The idea is that you do *not* create descendants for an existing hierarchy, but you create classes and possibly class hierarchies for specific responsibilities. When you want to save an instance of an existing class, instead of calling `SomeClass.SaveToText`, you would instantiate a `TSaver` and pass it an instance of the class to be saved.

A **very naive** implementation could look like the following.

```
type
  TSaver = class(TObject)
    procedure SaveToText; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TBaseHierarchySaver = class(TSaver)
  private
    FBase: TBaseClass;
  public
    constructor Create(aBase: TBaseClass);
    procedure SaveToText; override;

    class procedure Save(aBase: TBaseClass);
  end;

constructor TBaseHierarchySaver.Create(aBase: TBaseClass);
begin
  FBase := aBase;
end;

class procedure TBaseHierarchySaver.Save(aBase: TBaseClass);
var
  Me: TSaver;
begin
  Me := TBaseHierarchySaver.Create(aBase);
  Me.SaveToText;
end;

procedure TBaseHierarchySaver.SaveToText;
var
  Str: TStrings;
begin
  Str := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Str.Add(Format('%s (%d)', [FBase.Name, FBase.ID]));
    if FBase.InheritsFrom(TDerivedClass) then
    begin
      Str.Add(Format('%d', [TDerivedClass(FBase).Age]));
      Str.Add(Format('%s', [TDerivedClass(FBase).Address]));
    end;
  finally
    Str.SaveToFile('SomeFileName');
    Str.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**I don't much like this. It's brittle. We can do better.**

There are many ways to make the above code much more flexible and/or provide for polymorphistic execution. For example TSaver could have a dictionary of anonymous methods tied to classes of TBaseClass. TSaver.SaveToText could then get a TBaseClass argument and be implemented to execute each of the anonymous methods for the class of the instance passed into it if it inherits from the class tied to that anonymous method.

```
type
  TBaseClassClass = class of TBaseClass;
  TAddInfoProc = reference to procedure(aBase: TBaseClass; aStr: TStrings);

  TSaver = class(TObject)
  class var
    FAddInfoClasses: TDictionary<TBaseClassClass, TAddInfoProc>;
  public
    class procedure RegisterAddInfoProc(aBase: TBaseClassClass; 
      aAddInfo: TAddInfoProc);

    class procedure SaveToText(aBase: TBaseClass);
  end;

TSaver.RegisterAddInfoProc(TBaseClass, procedure(aBase: TBaseClass; aStr: TStrings)
  begin
    aStr.Add(Format('%s (%d)', [aBase.Name, aBase.ID]));
  end
);

TSaver.RegisterAddInfoProc(TDerivedClass, procedure(aBase: TBaseClass; aStr: TStrings)
  begin
    aStr.Add(Format('%d', [TDerivedClass(FBase).Age]));
    aStr.Add(Format('%s', [TDerivedClass(FBase).Address]));
  end
);
```

This frees you from inheritance hierarchies, but if you want polymorphistic execution, this could be changed to a dictionary tying specific TBaseClass descendants to a matching hierarchy of "AddInfo" descendants, where each AddInfo descendant adds its own information:

```
type
  TAddInfo = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure AddInfo(aBase: TBaseClass; aStr: TStrings); virtual;
  end;

  TDerivedAddInfo = class(TAddInfo)
  public
    procedure AddInfo(aBase: TBaseClass; aStr: TStrings); override;
  end;

procedure TAddInfo.AddInfo(aBase: TBaseClass; aStr: TStrings);
begin
  aStr.Add(Format('%s (%d)', [aBase.Name, aBase.ID]));
end;

procedure TDerivedAddInfo.AddInfo(aBase: TBaseClass; aStr: TStrings);
var
  Derived: TDerivedClass absolute aBase;
begin
  inherited;
  if not aBase.InheritsFrom(TDerivedClass) then Exit;

  aStr.Add(Format('%d', [Derived.Age]));
  aStr.Add(Format('%s', [Derived.Address]));
end;

type
  TBaseClassClass = class of TBaseClass;
  TAddInfoClass = class of TAddInfo;

  TSaver = class(TObject)
  class var
    FAddInfoClasses: TDictionary<TBaseClassClass, TAddInfoClass>;
  public
    class procedure RegisterAddInfoClass(aBase: TBaseClassClass; 
      aAddInfo: TAddInfoClass);

    class procedure SaveToText(aBase: TBaseClass);
  end;
```

Which by the way looks very much like the class helper method proposed elsewhere but without the limitation of having only one class helper active at any one time. So you could have TSaver, TPrinter, TMailer and whatever else you would like to be able to do with TBaseClass that isn't its prime responsibility.

Oh, by the way, the above use of absolute is one of the very few use case for absolute that I can stand. It is convenient short hand for a hard cast that is made safe by the early exit constraint which itself is also one of the few use cases for early exits that I can stand :-)

Comment: if only IDE parser would work correctly with absolute keyword...

PS bringing "Absolute" as part of type declaration rather than var name declaration is another Borland craziness :-)

Comment: Can you provide the full unit interface + implementation for your solution? I can't well understand how to set pieces togheter.

Comment: @OwK: hmmm. I'll see if I can find some time over the weekend. No promises though.

Comment: @OwK: Put together a sample project for you with example code for both a parallel hierarchy and registry of anonymous methods. May even write up an article about it, but that'll have to wait. Example can be found at: http://bjmsoftware.com/delphistuff/stackoverflow/extend-delphi-class-hierarchy%20(Q_11883474).zip